# How to write a chemical formula?

Tags: typography, chemistry

In order to produce the following output involving a chemical formula

[image]

I can attempt to write the chemical formula as a mathematical formula:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    As the scintillator $\text{PbWO}_{\text{4}}$ crystals are used.
\end{document}
```

However, this method is a brute force when approaching a chemical formula. How would a versed Latex expert solve this task?

Comment: See the package `mhchem` for example, especially its `\ce` macro

Answer (score 46, accepted):

[This](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Chemical_Graphics) might help you.

It boils down to using the package

```
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
```

or

```
\usepackage{chemformula}
```

which then allows you to use, e.g.,

```
\ce{3H2O} \\
\ce{1/2H2O} \\
\ce{AgCl2-} \\
\ce{H2_{(aq)}}
```

or

```
\ch{3 H2O} \\
\ch{1/2 H2O} \\
\ch{AgCl2-} \\
\ch{H2_{(aq)}}
```

respectively.

Comment: Is there any diffence between `mhchem` and `chemformula`? Is there one that is considered more "standard" than the other by chemistry editors?

Comment: I'm not aware of one being more standard.