# Multi-line equation alignment

Tags: equations, alignment

I want to use multi-line equation in my essay but when I use it the alignment of the equations become destruct.
please help me, thank you in advance

this is my code:

```
\documentclass[5p,fleqn]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\modulolinenumbers[10]
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
z=0, \forall r \in [R_i,R_o]: (uC_i)=(uC_i)_{in}, T=T_{in}, \\
P=P_{in}, (u_p C_{j,p})=0, \\
i=CH_4,H_2O, CO, CO_2,  j=H_2O,H_2 
\label{E21}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
r=r_0, \forall z \in [0,L]: \frac{\partial (uC_i)}{\partial r}=0,\\
k_a \frac{\partial T}{\partial r}=h_w (T_w-T)
\label{E22}
\end{split}
\end{equation}


\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
r=r_i, \forall z \in [0,L]: \frac{\partial (uC_i)}{\partial r}=0,\\
 i=CH_4,H_2O, CO, CO_2,\\
\frac{d_p}{Pe_m}\frac{\partial (uC_j)}{\partial r}=N_m, j=H_2,\\      
\frac{\partial T}{\partial r}=0 
\label{E23}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

the result attached, [image]

Comment: [Crosspost](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=32065)

Comment: It is still unclear to me what you are trying to align where.

Comment: I wanna to design my formula start from left edge of my essay and continue to right, I apologize in advance because I'm a beginner in latex

Comment: The description "I wanna design my formula [to] start from left edge of my essay and continue to right" is rather uninformative and nonspecific. Please be a lot more specific.

Answer (score 1):

[Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). I have the same opinion with @Mico, that you should explain what you want more, or at least we need a picture stating what you need, so that we don't have to guess :)

Anyway, I think this is what you need:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{align}
    &\begin{array}{l}
        z=0, \forall r \in [R_i,R_o]: (uC_i)=(uC_i)_{in},    T=T_{in},\\
        P=P_{in}, (u_p C_{j,p})=0,\\
        i=CH_4,H_2O, CO, CO_2,  j=H_2O,H_2
    \end{array}\label{something1}\\[2ex]
    &\begin{array}{l}
        r=r_0, \forall z \in [0,L]: \dfrac{\partial (uC_i)}{\partial r}=0,\\
        k_a \dfrac{\partial T}{\partial r}=h_w (T_w-T)
    \end{array}\label{something2}\\[2ex]
    &\begin{array}{l}
        r=r_i, \forall z \in [0,L]: \dfrac{\partial (uC_i)}{\partial r}=0,\\
        i=CH_4,H_2O, CO, CO_2,\\
        \dfrac{d_p}{Pe_m}\dfrac{\partial (uC_j)}{\partial r}=N_m, j=H_2,\\[2ex]
        \dfrac{\partial T}{\partial r}=0 
    \end{array}\label{something3}
\end{align}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

As for the chemical symbols like H2O, CO2..., I recommend using a package which is designed for chemistry. See other TeX.SX questions relating to this, for instance,  [How to write a chemical formula?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384610/how-to-write-a-chemical-formula), etc. I'm sorry not to use it in the code above, because I have never used it :)

Comment: Thank you very much dear, You exactly do what I want.
Thanks :)